# Titanium ListViews with data collection

Tags: android, ios, listview, titanium, titanium-alloy

In my titanium app i have to show a list of elements, to do so i am using the following view:

```
<Alloy>
    <Collection src="featuredEvents"/>
    <Window id="win" class="container" navBarHidden="true" exitOnClose="true" onOpen="showIndicator">
      <View id="navView"></View>
      <ActivityIndicator id="activityIndicator" message="L('loading')" />

            <TableView id="featuredEvents" dataCollection="featuredEvents" dataFilter="filterEvents" opacity="0" class="list">
                <TableViewRow eventId="{alloy_id}"  onClick="showEvent">
                    <View class="event-wrapper">
                        <ImageView image="{img}" eventId="{alloy_id}"  defaultImage="/img/loading.jpg"/>
                        <View class="eventImageOverlayYellow" eventId="{alloy_id}">
                            <Label id="eventName" text="{name}" eventId="{alloy_id}" />
                            <View id="eventTypeContainer" class="iconedLabelBig">
                                <ImageView image="{icon}" class="iconBig" />
                                <Label id="eventType" text="{type}" eventId="{alloy_id}" />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TableViewRow>
            </TableView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

it is working fine but the performance on android is really bad, so I want to rewrite the same list using ListView instead of TableView.
This is what i came up with:

```
<Alloy>
    <Collection src="featuredEvents"/>
    <Window id="win" class="container" navBarHidden="true" exitOnClose="true" onOpen="showIndicator">
      <View id="navView"></View>
      <ActivityIndicator id="activityIndicator" message="L('loading')" />

            <ListView id="featuredEvents" dataCollection="featuredEvents" dataFilter="filterEvents" opacity="0" class="list">
                <ListSection eventId="{alloy_id}"  onClick="showEvent">
                    <ListItem class="event-wrapper">
                        <ImageView image="{img}" eventId="{alloy_id}"  defaultImage="/img/loading.jpg"/>
                        <View class="eventImageOverlayYellow" eventId="{alloy_id}">
                            <Label id="eventName" text="{name}" eventId="{alloy_id}" />
                            <View id="eventTypeContainer" class="iconedLabelBig">
                                <ImageView image="{icon}" class="iconBig" />
                                <Label id="eventType" text="{type}" eventId="{alloy_id}" />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </ListItem>
                </ListSection>
            </ListView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

My controller index.js:

```
function showIndicator(e){}
$.win.open();
```

When I run it i got the following error:

```
Location:
alloy/controllers/index.js

Message:
Uncaught typeError: cannot read property '_transform' of null

Source:
title:"undefined" != typeof $model__transform["name"] ? $model._
```

-Is there an example of ListView used in combination of alloy data collections?

-Any idea what that error means?

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with `ListView` today also so I am no expert, but maybe I can help.  I read the documentation on the difference between `ListView`s and `TableView`s here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListView  I also got some good help from this question which is one of the few examples of `ListView`s with Alloy.  [Titanium Alloy ListView Nested Model Array of Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722623/titanium-alloy-listview-nested-model-array-of-tags/22875005#22875005)

From the documentation in the first link:

A `ListItem` object is not created in the same method as a `TableViewRow`. A `ListItem` is created by passing an array of `ListDataItem` objects to the `ListSection`.

You cannot add views to a `ListItem` using the add method, which could be done with a `TableViewRow`. To add views to a `ListItem`, you need to define an `ItemTemplate`, which is bound to a list data item using the template property.

You cannot explicitly set properties or bind events for a `ListItem`. You have to set them using the properties dictionary of a `ListDataItem` or `ItemTemplate` and the events dictionary of the `ItemTemplate` or `ViewTemplate`, respectively.

As for your error I got similar ones when I was trying to pass a variable directly into the template as had been done with the `TableRow`.  Instead I had to populate the variable that was bound to the temple with extra properties.  Not sure if that is recommended, but it worked.